# Contour Plot: Selecting the contour line that crosses a specific point

Tags: plotting, graphics, conditional

I have a very complicated function $f(u,v)$ in the complex $u,v$ plane which has several contours with the same value $x$, so that when I draw a `ContourPlot` of the equation $f(u,v)=x$ I get several lines (far too many, it crowds the graphic).

However, I am actually only interested in those contours that cross a given point $(u_0,v_0)$ of my function. Consider the following minimal working example:

```
ContourPlot[u Cos[v] == 1, {u, -3, 3}, {v, -3, 3}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0}]}]
```

[image: Full Contour]

I would like to single out the contour which crosses the point $(1,0)$ (indicated by the red dot) and throw the other contours away:

[image: Desired outcome]

How do I implement the condition that the contour must cross a given point?

**NB:** For the MWE above, it is simple to exclude the unwanted contours by specifying $x<0$. I am not interested in that. I have a very messy function and the only criteria that separates the contour of interest from the others is that it crosses a point of interest.

---

**EDIT:**

So I have come up with an example that reproduces my issue with klgr's very good solution: all contours disappear, even the one of interest.

If I come up with a slightly more complicated function where the contours touch then this method cannot choose the line which crosses the point of interest:

```
ContourPlot[1/x Cos[y] == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},MaxRecursion -> 6, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0}]}]
```

[image: more complicated example]

If I use klgr's method however,

```
Normal[ContourPlot[1/x Cos[y] == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, MaxRecursion -> 6, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0}]}]] /. l_Line :> If[RegionMember[l, {1, 0}], l, Nothing]
```

[image: not working example]

then all contours vanish!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to post-process to remove the contour lines that do not pass through `{1,0}`:

```
Normal[ContourPlot[u Cos[v] == 1, {u, -3, 3}, {v, -3, 3}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0}]}] ] /. 
    l_Line :> If[RegionMember[l, {1, 0}], l, Nothing]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can add the option `PlotPoints -> 100` to get something that works for both examples in OP:

```
cp1 = ContourPlot[1/x Cos[y] == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0}]}, 
   ImageSize -> Small];
Row[{cp1, 
  Normal[cp1] /. l_Line :> If[RegionMember[l, {1, 0}], l, Nothing]}]
```

[image]

If we color the three pieces of the contour individually:

```
i = 1; cp2 = 
 ContourPlot[1/x Cos[y] == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0}]}, 
   ImageSize -> Small] /. l_Line :> {ColorData[97][i++], l};
Row[{cp2, 
  Normal[cp2] /. l_Line :> If[RegionMember[l, {1, 0}], l, Nothing]}]
```

[image]

With `Exlusions -> None` one of the pieces is a closed curve:

```
i = 1;
cp3 = ContourPlot[1/x Cos[y] == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0}]}, 
    ImageSize -> Small] /. l_Line :> {ColorData[97][i++], l};
Row[{cp3, 
  Normal[cp3] /. l_Line :> If[RegionMember[l, {1, 0}], l, Nothing]}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Comment: So this solution seems to work for the MWE. However, in my code the method rules out **all** contour lines. I'm thinking the issue might be to do with Accuracy or Precision between ContourPlot and how I specify my point but I haven't found a work around. Any suggestions?

Comment: @OldTomMorris, maybe something like `l_Line :> If[RegionDisjoint[l, Disk[{1, 0}, .001]], Nothing, l]` in `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: The only issue being I am running Mathematica 10.3 and not 11.1!

Comment: @OldTomMorris, have you tried increasing `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`?

Comment: Yes. `PlotPoints -> 50` and `MaxRecursion -> 4` give me nothing too. I also tried a variant of the `RegionDisjoint` using `Element` but that didn't sem to work either.

Comment: Have re-edited question and provided an example of when the method fails. Is it of any use?

Comment: @OldTomMorris,please see the update.

Comment: have now tried `PlotPoints -> 200` and still no success. I'm thinking the problem is another but I cannot see why your method shouldn't work.

Comment: Have tried the solution with `l_Line :> If[RegionDisjoint[l, Disk[{1, 0}, .001]], Nothing, l]` in Mathematica 11. It works, have now accepted the solution, thanks for your patience!